# Is using a switch enough to hide MAC adresses of my devices from my ISP?

Tags: network, privacy, mac-address

I guess that my question sounds particularly dumb for specialists, but I was unable to find a reliable answer trough Google, so eventually I decided to post it here.

I have a router obtained from ISP.

In order to prevent seeing all my MACs from provider's side, is it enough to use a network switch? 
Or I should buy a second router on my own, disable WAN management so he can see only one MAC (belonging to 2nd router)?

Comment: What makes you think that the ISP will be able to see your local devices' MAC addresses? The router will use its own MAC address when sending traffic to/from the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

The router will know all of the MAC addresses since that is part of its purpose. If the ISP has remote access to the router then they will always be able to see that information in the ARP table.

Whether putting in an inner router will help is somewhat debatable - it *should* help but it may not be totally possible to guarantee that no data will leak.

Does it matter? What is more important is whether the ISP might listen in on any traffic, I can't imagine that it would profit them in anyway so the risk is probably pretty low. However, the possibility exists.

What might be a better option would be to put in a VPN terminating proxy. Such a device would act as a proxy channelling all of your data down a VPN tunnel and so no unencrypted traffic would be visible to the ISP. A decent router such as the Ubiquity EdgeRouter Lite would give you that capability.

Indeed, an inner router is not an uncommon architecture when using high-speed broadband (>8M, e.g. Fibre To The Cabinet) as the ISP often puts in a "modem", sometimes referred to as a "residential gateway". What this really is is a router with a phone connection upstream and Ethernet downstream. You connect your own (or the ISP's) router to the Ethernet connection and the router "dials" the address of the ISP to connect. The gateway is typically locked down and you can't see anything on it nor make any changes. In this case you can choose whether or not to use a VPN. If you don't, the ISP would be able to sniff your traffic and could work out that you have multiple machines but isn't *likely* to be able to be more specific.